# AD LDS - Login with Bind user does not work

Tags: active-directory, adlds

I tried to replace our ApacheDS LDAP System with the AD LDS.

I installed and setup the basic AD LDS, created a user called "Admin" and added him to the "Reader" Group, i also tried to add a password with rightclick the user and reset password, but i can't see any set password in the user..

Anyways, when i try to connect to the AD LDS instance with the Bind credentials, i got the message that they are invalid. (Error 49)

Here is my User that i created:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

Here is what i see in LDP.exe when i use the simple bind

```
    -----------
res = ldap_simple_bind_s(ld, 'Admin@example.com', <unavailable>); // v.3
Error <49>: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed: Invalid Credentials
Server error: 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v4563
Error 0x8009030C The logon attempt failed
```

[image]

Comment: You will never see a password set. How are you trying to authenticate? Through code? Or a command line tool?

Comment: Actually i try to connect with ANSI Edit with the bind user which is not working, in the end goal i would need to auth over a IBM Product, which uses a simple bind (and java behind the scenes)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show how you're entering the credentials or the full error message so this is a stab in the dark.

AD will never show you the password - not even the encrypted password - so that's normal.

When it comes to authenticating, AD doesn't use the full DN like other LDAP servers do. I suspect maybe that's what you're doing? You have to give it one of the two [user name formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/user-name-formats), which can be found in these attributes on the user object:

- The `userPrincipalName` attribute: this is in the format of username@example.com
- The `sAMAccountName` attribute. This is what is normally referred to when someone says "username". If you're authenticating to a different domain than the user account is on, then you must include the NetBIOS name of the domain: `EXAMPLE\username`. If you're authenticating to the same domain, then the domain is optional.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.

I don't have a sAMAccountName, as i use AD LDS without the Domain Services (as i read this attribute just exist in the big AD).

So if i understand correctly i should use the userPrincipalName attribute set it to Admin then in my case i would enter "Admin@example.com"? I will give this a shot and edit the error message if it does not work.

Comment: The "data 2030" is the hex value of the Windows error code, which corresponds to [`ERROR_DS_NO_SUCH_OBJECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--8200-8999-#:~:text=ERROR_DS_NO_SUCH_OBJECT). So it definitely doesn't like the user you're using. I notice in your screenshot that Admin is an inetOrgUser. Does authentication work if you use a simple user account (like UserAdmin)? I don't have any experience with AD LDS.

Comment: Sadly no it does not work with the simple user Account, its exactly the same issue here.

Created this User to test if i made a mistake with converting the ApacheDS setup to AD LDS

Answer (score 0):

Solved this, i just need to use "Admin" as a Login username, without the domain etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).